# linear regression and/or strength of association between two data sets - matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

Excuse the very simple/stupid question, but...

Say I have the following (in matlab):

```
x_A = rand(1,30);
y_A = rand(1,30);
x_B = rand(1,40);
y_B = rand(1,40);

scatter(x_A,y_A,'r')
hold on
scatter(x_B,y_B,'b')
```

I want to see if there is any correlation between red and blue points, e.g. how well can blue be a predictor of red? How strongly are they associated? Given that lengths of the data sets A and B are not equal, I can't simply do a linear regression (can I?). Please help!

Comment: Your question seems more about statistics than matlab. Try here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

usually I would apply [Pearson correlation](http://www10.org/cdrom/papers/519/node13.html)  for similarity in two dataset( int the example you have given in the question the dimension of is 1 )

Pearson correlation coefficient reflects the degree of linear correlation between two variables, its value between [-1, 1]. When the linear relationship between two variables increases, the correlation coefficient tends to 1 or -1; one variable increases when the other variables increases, indicating a positive correlation between them, the correlation coefficient is greater than 0; If a variable gain large, but another variable decreases, indicating a negative correlation between them, the correlation coefficient is less than 0; If the correlation coefficient is equal to 0, indicating that there is no linear correlation between them.